# How setup client-server simulation environment for development using J2ME and NCF

Tags: java, .net, java-me, emulation, nokia

Appreciation in advance,

I’m a newbie in mobile development and developing a twitter like app using J2ME. I have developed server side app using .NET and it uses a GSM Interface to intercept binary SMS messages sent by J2ME client app. The system works in practice however it costs too much each time to test new features with a real device. In addition to that I have just one mobile phone and I’m not able to test multiple user scenarios.

I tried to test the app using Nokia S40 SDK emulator and NCF (Nokia Connectivity Framework) however I’m just able to exchange messages between two instances of emulator.

Is there any way to setup a simulated environment in which I simply use the S40 emulator running client app and sent binary messages being routed to a local port on the PC. This way I can develop a middleware catching routed messages from that port and deliver it to server side engine and vice versa.

I think such environment can save lots of money for other developers too.

Any idea?